# wp_pagenavi on WP_Query using customfields

Tags: wp-query

I have been searching this subject for some time now, not finding a solution.
First of all, sorry for my bad spelling. 
Im quit new to PHP, so please be gental.

Im using this to list some customfields:

```
<?php
$my_query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type'=>'post',
    'posts_per_page'=>'1'
));


while ($my_query->have_posts())
{
    $my_query->the_post();

    $emne = get_field( "emne" );
    $titel = get_field( "titel" );
    $forfatter = get_field( "forfatter" );
    $billede = get_field( "billede" );
    $land = get_field( "om_foredragsholder" );

    { ?>



    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" style="cursor:pointer;">
    <div class="content-holder-whitebox">
        <div class="whitebox">
            <div class="left">
                <h2><?php echo $emne ?></h2>
                <div class="title">"<?php echo $titel ?>"</div>
                <div class="navn"><?php echo $forfatter ?></div>
                <div class="mere-info">Mere info</div>
          </div>
             <div class="right">
             <div class="billede">
                    <img src="<?php echo $billede ?>" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="knap">
                    <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/booknu.jpg" />
                    </div>
          </div>
      </div>            
     </div>
    </a>

    <?php
    }
}
```

?>

Please, can some one help me getting   working? 
I have installed the plugin WP-PageNavi.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one you need to add `'paged' => get_query_var('page')` so your code in $my_query should be like this

```
$my_query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type'=>'post',
    'posts_per_page'=>'1',
    'paged' => get_query_var('paged')
));
```

You just need to pass along the ‘paged’ query var from the main query:

You can see also Codex page on [query_posts()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/query_posts)